# Add a google+ event to calendar via api

Tags: google-plus, google-calendar-api

is this possible?

I want to add a public event from a google+ page to users calendar with api calls. Unfortunately, the google+ api returns not all information about the event. So i'm searching for an option to add this event to the calendar like the "take part" button on google+.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex, have you tried

> [*Sharing interactive posts*](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive)
>
> Interactive posts provide an easy and prominent way to allow users to share your site or app with their connections and invite them to take action, for example, *RSVP for an event*.

To add a add button to your site:

```
<script >
window.___gcfg = {
lang: 'zh-CN',
parsetags: 'onload'
};
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer></script>
```

Then create your button:

```
<!-- Place the tag where you want the button to render -->
<button
class="g-interactivepost"
data-contenturl="https://plus.google.com/pages/"
data-contentdeeplinkid="/pages"
data-clientid="xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
data-prefilltext="Engage your users today, create a Google+ page for your business."
data-calltoactionlabel="CREATE"
data-calltoactionurl="http://plus.google.com/pages/create"
data-calltoactiondeeplinkid="/pages/create">
Tell your friends
</button>
```